# Javascript unwanted closure behavior

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I was trying to code something similar to this :

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    funcs[i]=function() {
        alert(i);
    };
}
```

Obviously, calling `funcs[0]` won't alert `0` as expected, simply because the variable `i` is captured by the anonymous function, and calling any of `funcs[0..4]` will alert '4' (the value of `i` after the last iteration and shared by all created functions).

The first work around that comes to my mind is using some kind of function generator :

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    funcs[i]=(function(cap) {
        return function() {alert(cap)};
    })(i);
}
```

This do the trick, but seems really puzzling and hard to read.  Is there any better way to get the intended behavior without using a function wrapper?

Comment: Couldn't you use `funcs[i].i = i;` after the function statement?

Comment: Can't recreate (Chrome 21 / Mac 10.7) http://jsfiddle.net/VDm5C/

Comment: Nop, because in the real case that I'm working on, the scope is set on calling the function `funcs[i].call(someObject, ..)`. This will override `this`, and `this.i` won't be accessible.

Comment: JavaScript scope is at the `function` level.  Thus when you create functions in another function, they share the parent function local variables. Opening a block (with `{ ... }`) does **not** create a new scope, as it does in C++ or Java.

Comment: @arxanas: No.  JavaScript doesn't work that way.

Comment: @sitifensys: As Pointy says, JS var scope is at function level. So you need to do whatever you want (which happens to be: create a function) inside the body of a function (to distinguish scope). Possibly hard to read but necessary.

Comment: @arxanas: Your example is slightly flawed.  It works because when you are calling each of the functions, you are in a `for` loop, and changing the value of `i` to be the correct value.  Change your 2nd `for` to use another var, and it won't work.  http://jsfiddle.net/VDm5C/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function allows you to pre-bind additional parameters to a bound function:

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    funcs[i]=function(i) {
        alert(i);
    }.bind(this, i);
}
```

This is an ES5 function, so should work on IE9+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox:

Comment: IE is still not a real browser :p (just trolling)

Answer (score 2):

You should write it as simple as you can. I think it's easy to understand, but hard to read. So one way to simplify it is to use Nested coding style. I don't think it can't be simpler than as it is now.

I'd suggest this way:

```
var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    funcs[i] = (
        function (cap) {
            return function () { alert(cap) };
        }
    )(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, named functions are often superior, for both performance and readability reasons. Why not do it like this:

```
function foo (cap) {
    return function () { alert(cap) };
}

var funcs = [];
for (var i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    funcs[i]=foo(i);
}
```

Comment: Because you need write a top-level function that is not used in any place else?

Comment: Jon: It doesn't have to be top-level, it just has to be in scope.

Comment: Sure, wrong expression on my part; pretend it's not there. It's still not ideal, it's really the same undesirable technique as e.g. creating classes to simulate closures in languages such as C++ and C#. Both of them have added lambdas specifically so that you don't have to write this kind of "machinery" code.

Comment: Ideal is subjective. Apparently, @sitifensys thinks the anonymous closure is not ideal. Why are we arguing this?

Comment: We are not. I just answered your rhetorical question by voicing an opinion.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, duly noted! Regrettably, there are neither magic bullets not pixie dust.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to embed your code with those anonymous functions, a solution is to define (named) class embedding both the state (i) and the function (in the prototype). That's more LOC but **sometimes** more readable :

```
var funcs = [];
function MyFunc(i) {
   this.i=i;
}
MyFunc.prototype.doIt = function(){
   alert(this.i);
};
for (var i=0; i<5 ; ++i) {
    funcs[i]=new MyFunc(i);
}

funcs[2].doIt();​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var funcs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map(function(i) {
    return function() {alert(i);};
});
```

Note: `map` isn't suppoted by IE8 and older, but there's a [common polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) for it.

Comment: I nearly wrote an answer like this, but then decided that `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` doesn't scale...

Comment: @Alnitak I know that feel, bro. I just wanted to show something different. This all belongs to some array generation algorithm. Maybe splitting strings, or creating `Uint8Array`, or whatever...

Comment: ah, now _that_ I _can_ solve: `Array.range = function f(m, n, z) { return m <=-- n ? (z = f(m, n), z.push(n), z) : [] };`